# Deleting the string element from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=['152525', '852452', '85965645', 'NOSUCHINSTANCE']
```

I have x as shown above i wanted to remove the 'NOSUCHINSTANCE' from the array so that my output would be:

```
x=['152525', '852452', '85965645']
```

I have tried using x=x.remove('NOSUCHINSTANCE')

but its throwing me an error, is there any other way to delete bases on index.

Comment: Did you try using `filter` or a list comp or anything?

Comment: x.pop(index_num)

Comment: No, can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: is there any chance to pop out using the index ex: x.pop(a[3])

Comment: @PeterMajko what do you mean by index_num, can you pleae explain me using the example i asked for in the previous comment